# Correct setup so Xcode generates properly symbolicated logs for iOS devices

Tags: xcode, symbolicatecrash

I'm performing testing on several iOS apps on a range of devices and iOS versions (iPhone, Touch, iPad, iOS 3.1.3, 4.0.2, 4.1).

I have Xcode v3.2.4 installed, primarily so I can get logs and console output to attach to bugs.

We recently noticed that my symbolicated logs are just the non-sybolicated logs with extra spaces inserted between existing characters (so "log file" appears as "l o g  f i l e".

One of the engineers eventually gave me a build with both a .app and a .dSYM which I copied to my Mac locally and installed onto a device through Xcode (usually use iPhone Config Util).

After that, the symbolicated files aren't spacey, but they are identical to the non-symbolicated versions.

What am I missing? What do I have configured incorrectly? What am I doing wrong?

I recognize that might be a big question, but I'm hoping it's not, or if it is, someone's feeling very kind and bored :)

Thanks ahead of time for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This always works for me, no matter how broken automatic symbolication on the machine is:

1. Copy the dSYM file to a location where it is definitely indexed by Spotlight (from experience: *not* the /tmp folder). A subfolder of Home, Desktop or Documents is the safest choice.
2. Call mdimport to ensure that Spotlight has indexed the folder containing the dSYM: `mdimport /path/to/dSYM`
3. Call symbolicatecrash (assuming you've got a reasonably current Xcode in Applications): `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDeviceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash /path/to/crashlog`

If it doesn't work, running symbolicatecrash with -v (verbose) will usually show pretty clearly where it's looking for the symbols and why they're not found.